# Flutter how to use multiple forloops

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this code but sometimes it runs the code in wrong order. Is it possible to wait for each for loop to finish before next one starts?

```
  void changeWeek() {
    for (int i = 0; i < newactivities.length; i++) {
   
      int year = DateTime.now().year;
      DateTime startDate = DateTime(year, 1, 1);
      while (startDate.weekday != DateTime.monday) {
        startDate = startDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
      }
      for (String weekday in newactivities[i].daylistdone) {
        int offset = (int.parse(weekday)) + (int.parse(currentweek) - 1) * 7;
        DateTime donedate = startDate.add(Duration(days: offset));
        oldDatesDone.add(Timestamp.fromDate(donedate));
      }
      for (String weekday in newactivities[i].daylist) {
        int offset =
            (int.parse(weekday) - 1) + (int.parse(currentweek) - 1) * 7;
        DateTime notdonedate = startDate.add(Duration(days: offset));
        oldDatesNotDone.add(Timestamp.fromDate(notdonedate));
      }

      for (var i in oldDatesDone) {
        oldDatesNotDone.remove(i);
      }

      finaloldDatesDone = newactivities[i].weekdaysdone + oldDatesDone;
      finaloldDatesNotDone = newactivities[i].weekdaysnotdone + oldDatesNotDone;

      act.add({
        'title': newactivities[i].title,
        'days': newactivities[i].daylist,
        'notificationidnumber': newactivities[i].notificationidnumber,
        'daysdone': myData22,
        'weekdaysdone': finaloldDatesDone,
        'weekdaysnotdone': finaloldDatesNotDone,
        'timelist': newactivities[i].timelist,
        'time': newactivities[i].time
      });

      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(widget.user.user.uid)
          .doc(documentName)
          .update({"activities": act});
    }
  }
```

Or can I do it in another way to solve the code?

Comment: What do you mean in wrong order?

Comment: It is something wrong with firebase upload I think. It doesn’t uploads all “activities”

Answer (score 2):

Your Firebase update returns a Future, so it is an asynchronous operation. To preserve order of calls, you need to `await` the result of this call:

```
void changeWeek() async {

// ...
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(widget.user.user.uid)
      .doc(documentName)
      .update({"activities": act});
}
```

Note that you need do declare the `changeWeek()` function as `async` for this to work.

Comment: It is something wrong with firebase upload I think. It doesn’t uploads all “activities”